# Airlink101 model #AWLL6075 finds network but drops packets in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, drivers

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10, 32-bit, and trying to get hooked up to wireless (I've been using ethernet until now, and it's no longer possible where I am living). I could try to set up a router with DD-WRT as an access point if I have to, but I already have an AirLink101 Golden N (model AWLL6075) dongle and would rather use that if possible. Ubuntu finds it okay, and it finds the network okay, and when I enter the password it tells me I've connected to the network - but nothing loads. Chrome just gives me "Unable to connect to the Internet" or "This website is unavailable," and when I do ifconfig, it shows a LOT of packet loss. What do I do? Is it a driver issue (I'm using whatever Ubuntu came with)? Or something else? Other devices in the house work fine.

Partial ifconfig:

`wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:2f:35:6d:2f

          inet addr:192.168.1.29  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:2fff:fe35:6d2f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39469 errors:0 dropped:445553 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34526 errors:0 dropped:1014 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27667361 (27.6 MB)  TX bytes:7729976 (7.7 MB)`

It eventually started "working," but still drops a lot of packets and stops working sporadically.

Comment: Please help us help you. You mention ifconfig shows a lot of packet loss. Show us. The more information you provide, the better the question and the better the answer

Comment: Edited to include the ifconfig info.

Comment: what model Airlink 101 do you have? Perhaps you can recognize it from http://airlink101.com/products/wireless.php

Comment: It says "Golden N," which I can only assume is the model...someone gave it to me.

Comment: for future reference its a model #AWLL6075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided IMHO it's RF interference.
This may be similar although the brand of wifi is different.
See if this link helps you and let us know![Rtl8187 wireless card drops signal within seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453110/rtl8187-wireless-card-drops-signal-within-seconds)

Comment: I might be silly...but RF interference sounds like a different thing than "buggy driver." I'm going to try dealing with the buggy driver thing first, but if RF interference is different, how do I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: @Rae Not silly at all. Sorry, wrong link!!!! airlink101 has no linux drivers or support

Comment: My roommate came home and suggested, based on your answer about RF interference, that I use a USB extender to bring the dongle up and away from my computer. It works beautifully so far. Thank you! I wouldn't have guessed RF on my own.

Comment: @Rae Excellent! Please answer your own question with the info in the comment so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Elder Geek's answer about RF interference, my roommate suggested I try a USB extension cable to bring the dongle up and away from my computer. The cable is only about a foot and a half long, but it worked beautifully - no new drivers necessary.