# Connect/Disconnect cycle with ALFA Networks AWUS036H in Ubuntu 16.04-64bit

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, realtek-wireless, alfa-wireless

I'm doing a personal project and wanted to leverage my ALFA card.  It isn't more than two seconds before I can see the card connect, then just as suddenly disconnect.  Here is my iwconfig info:

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan1     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any
>            Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=30 dBm
>            Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>            Encryption key:off
>            Power Management:off
>
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"********"
>            Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point:
>            A8:D0:E5:34:4D:C3
>            Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm
>            Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>            Encryption key:off
>            Power Management:on
>            Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm
>            Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>            Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:603   Missed beacon:0>
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.

It shows that my wlan0 is the on-board wifi card and it is functioning normally.  However the wlan1 is the alfa networks card is is definitely not displaying the same information: bitrate, txrate and a few other things are missing.  I'm suspecting that the powermanagement is the issue because I compile all my drivers from source and haven't had any issues with the ARCH and Kali2.0 machines I'm using in my lab...

I've edited my rc.local file to allow for a correct txrate and power also.

> sudo cat /etc/rc.local 
>      #!/bin/sh -e
>      #
>      #rc.local
>      #
>      # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
>      # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
>      # value on error.
>      #
>      # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
>      # bits.
>      #
>      # By default this script does nothing.
>
> iwconfig wlan1 rate 48M auto
>
> iwconfig wlan1 frag 512
>
> iwconfig wlan1 rts 512
>
> iwconfig wlan1 txpower 30
>
> exit 0

Anyone have some good thoughts on this?  I'll try and provide any information that I can to help this diagnosis go smoothly.

Edit per request: sudo lshw -C network

> ```
> sudo lshw -C network   *-network               
>    description: Ethernet interface
>    product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
>    vendor: Intel Corporation
>    physical id: 19
>    bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
>    logical name: eth0
>    version: 04
>    serial: 54:ee:75:43:a4:d2
>    capacity: 1Gbit/s
>    width: 32 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
>    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.6-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
> port=twisted pair
>    resources: irq:44 memory:f0500000-f051ffff memory:f053e000-f053efff ioport:3080(size=32)   *-network
>    description: Wireless interface
>    product: Wireless 7260
>    vendor: Intel Corporation
>    physical id: 0
>    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>    logical name: wlan0
>    version: bb
>    serial: cc:3d:82:1e:a2:df
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-65-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=10.120.32.201
> latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
>    resources: irq:49 memory:f0400000-f0401fff   *-network
>    description: Wireless interface
>    physical id: 2
>    bus info: usb@2:2
>    logical name: wlan1
>    serial: 00:c0:ca:83:07:b2
>    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=4.4.0-65-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes
> wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
> ```

Update as of 20170302 @ 1520 Central

The alfa card is still responding the same as before.  Connection followed by a disconection.

iwconfig settings:

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan1     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any
>             Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
>             Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Encryption key:off
>             Power Management:off
>              wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Public-WIFI"
>             Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 18:64:72:80:28:00
>             Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm
>             Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Encryption key:off
>             Power Management:on
>             Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm
>             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>             Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.

sudo lshw -C network

> *-network
>          description: Ethernet interface
>          product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
>          vendor: Intel Corporation
>          physical id: 19
>          bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
>          logical name: eth0
>          version: 04
>          serial: 54:ee:75:43:a4:d2
>          capacity: 1Gbit/s
>          width: 32 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
>          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.6-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
>   port=twisted pair
>          resources: irq:44 memory:f0500000-f051ffff memory:f053e000-f053efff ioport:3080(size=32)   *-network
>          description: Wireless interface
>          product: Wireless 7260
>          vendor: Intel Corporation
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>          logical name: wlan0
>          version: bb
>          serial: cc:3d:82:1e:a2:df
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>          configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-65-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=10.192.136.177
>   latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
>          resources: irq:49 memory:f0400000-f0401fff   *-network
>          description: Wireless interface
>          physical id: 2
>          bus info: usb@2:1
>          logical name: wlan1
>          serial: 00:c0:ca:83:07:b2
>          capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>          configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=4.4.0-65-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes
>   wireless=IEEE 802.11bg

[wifi troubleshooting script results](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24097272/)

I'm still stumped with what's wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide at the very least the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and ideally the output from the [wireless script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425180/225694)

Comment: working on ^^wireless script now

Comment: Note that the output of `lsb_release -a` will tell you the exact version of Ubuntu you are running and as I recall 16.04.2 provided a new [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack) which **might** provide better support for your hardware.

Comment: [wifi_script_results](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24097272/)

Comment: Thank you @ElderGeek for the above link to the stack information.  So you are thinking that by applying one of the kernel_livepatches **might** correct this issue?  I will try this and report back with my results. Thank you again.

Comment: That's the hope. Perhaps the last 2 lines of code [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/456676/225694) might be useful.  Same chipset. reported to work on 14.04 at the end of the comments. My apologies for the delay. I had an important phone interview.

Comment: Sorry to put you through all the editing, but it appears that I answered this question some time ago. This is a possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453110/rtl8187-wireless-card-drops-signal-within-seconds

Comment: Still no luck with either of those.  I do notice that the light on the ALFA is lighting up a lot more now than before but still losing connecting and disconnecting.

Comment: Is there any improvement whatsoever? It would be typical to get a more solid connection. Can you try hte settings that were successful for hexafraction [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453110/rtl8187-wireless-card-drops-signal-within-seconds#comment605734_456676)

Comment: No luck with that either.  In a terminal session I cannot get the commands to go through to the alfa card.  It is still connecting and disconnecting so rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot issue commands to the USB adapter I can think of only 2 possibilities.

1) A faulty connection to the Universal Serial Bus (this can be caused by a number of factors.

Any port can be affected by excessive dust. I've had systems show up in my shop with similar problems and simply blowing the offending port out with canned air has resolved the connectivity issue.

The front ports on a desktop are connected via a harness to headers on the mainboard. Damage can occur to this harness if care isn't taken to avoid pinching it when closing the case. An intermittent short in this harness can cause the same result.

2) A faulty wireless adapter could also cause this problem.

To ascertain if the ALFA Networks AWUS036H is the problem test it in a different system and see if the problem follows that device.

To ascertain if it's a connectivity issue with the USB bus, you can [test continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_test) through the harness if so equipped. To perform a physical examination of the offending check to see if the device fits as tightly in the port you are using as in other ports and of course check visually for bent connectors or dust packed in the port.

Sources:

Experience

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_test

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dead-usb-port-heres-how-to-diagnose-and-fix-it/